# Creative Zen does not work in Banshee or Rhythmbox

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox, creative-zen, mtp

Neither Banshee nor Rhythmbox will see files on Creative Zen. Right Clicking on Zen Player  and selecting "properties" causes both Banshee and Rhythmbox to exit.

All MTP plugins & libraries seem to be installed.

This worked perfectly on 10.10.

Issue replicated on several 11.10 installations on Acer Aspire desktop, Acer 5552 Laptop and Panasonic CF52 laptop.

Answer (score 2):

To use your Creative Zen on 11.10, you can try [Gnomad 2](http://gnomad2.sourceforge.net) : 
`sudo apt-get install gnomad2`.

It works perfectly for my Creative Zen Micro on 11.10.